# Why is tensor being converted to numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

For some reason, the tensor datatype is being changed to a numpy array in the second iteration. I can't figure out why.

```
y_true = torch.tensor([])
y_pred = torch.tensor([])
for i, (x,y) in enumerate(zip(feature_testloader,label_testloader), 0):
    print(i,type(y_true))
    optimizer.zero_grad()   
    output = self.forward(x)
    target = y
    y_true = torch.cat((y_true, target))
    _, pred_class = torch.max(output, dim=1)
    y_pred = torch.cat((y_pred, pred_class))
```

Output from print statement above:

```
0 <class 'torch.Tensor'>
1 <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Comment: Can you provide examples of `y` from `label_testloader`? The concatenation of this is what is affecting `y_true`

Comment: [torch.cat](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cat.html) is supposed to return a torch.Tensor, and it does not accept numpy.array as input

Comment: Can you print out the type of target?